# Find $xy+yz+zx$, given quadratic form of equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Given that $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^+$ and the following equations:

$$x^2 + y^2 + xy = 1,$$
$$y^2 + z^2 + yz = 2,$$
$$z^2 + x^2 + xz = 3.$$

How to find $xy + yz + zx$? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Can you add details of what you tried to do?

Comment: ya i tried to eliminate x and y and landed to a 4th degree equation of z.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider a triangle ABC. 
         take a point inside triangle say O. such that sides subtend angle of 2π/3 each.
let OA = x, OB = y, OC = z.
So sides will come out 1, √2, √3. ( cosine rule ).
as triangle is right angled, area  = 1/2*√2
Also add up area of triangle formed by smaller ones we get,
       xy + yz + zx = √(8/3).